# Object renders without proper shading

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, import, shaders, lighting

just signed up to write this question.

So I recently downloaded an **.obj** file to animate around in Blender.

Now in textured view, whenever I move around my lighting, it shades just fine like this:

[image: A normal object]

But when I start rendering, the object comes out with plain textures, no shading of any sort:

[image]

Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

[This is the link to the files and the original .obj file **all included!** (Google Drive)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oCZUZkskE0vTIt0WqNUTMtrPYevdLb_h/view?usp=sharing)

I shall await your answers...

...please.

P.S: I use *Blender* render

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Nov material tab you have to raise some diffuse and specular values, and uncheck the "use alpha" option of the NovLight ke emission texture.

[image]

Comment: Oh ho ho! Thank you very much! Solved it right away.